# Top command in init.d script

Tags: bash, shell, centos, init.d

i have a init.d script and a bash file. The init.d script execute my bash. The problem is when the bash uses a top command, the variable uso it's always empty. When i execute just the script, the script works fine. The OS is CentOS.

The bash script handles the process mysqld. When the process is over the minimo value, the script write a log.

Here is my bash code

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Inicio" >> /path/of/file.log
minimo=1
while true
do
    uso=$(top -n 1 | grep mysqld | awk '{ print $10 }')
    if [ -n "$uso" ]
    then
        echo "El uso es:    $uso" >> /path/of/file.log
        if [ $( awk -v uso=$uso -v minimo=$minimo 'BEGIN { if(uso>minimo) print 1; else print 0}' ) -eq 1 ]
        then
            echo $(date)" ------ "$uso >> /path/of/file.log
            sleep 5s
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-b` option to run `top` in batch mode. It normally requires access to a terminal, and init.d scripts aren't in an interactive session.

```
uso=$(top -b -n 1 | awk '/mysqld/ { print $10 }')
```